# Saving a Float Variable with less than 64bit in PYTHON

Tags: python

In my PYTHON program, I am loading a lot of (floating) numbers for later use. I am talking about 100 Million numbers or more. It seems that I run into problems with memory space on RAM. Since the numbers I am saving do not need to have a high precision (3-4 digits would be more than enough) and are usually small (in the range -1000 .. 1000) I do not use the precision provided by a 64bit float.

Is there a possibility to save a floating number using less memory (maybe 8 or 16 bit)?

Thank you!

Comment: "...100 Million numbers or more. It seems I run into problems with memory space on RAM." Really? You expected to be able to compute more than 100 Million numbers with, say, 8 gigs of ram?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the types in the numpy library, which provides the following types of interest:

```
float_
float16
float32
float64
```

So, if you wanted a 16-bit floating point number (1 sign bit, 5 exponent, and 
10 for the mantissa), you could use the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.float16(10.0)
```

See also, [data types in NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)

Answer (score 1):

Pack them into arrays of float-format values using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) package's `f` format.